# Maven Error while creating Web-App Exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Cannot access defaults field of Properties

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am creating a Spring MVC project. I selected webapp archtype and also included libraries for tomcat. But the Pom.xml is showing the following error.

```
Exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Cannot access defaults field of Properties [in thread "Worker-6: Creating maven-archetype-webapp"]
```

The Pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.aryan.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>springmvc1</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>springmvc1 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>springmvc1</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like there is plugin missing add this to remove error

```
`<plugin>
```

org.apache.maven.plugins
maven-install-plugin
2.5.2`